# Screenshot of Notifications on Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notification-bar, screenshots

There is a notification in Chinese showing on my Android Lollipop screen. I'd like to get a translation but have no access to a Chinese speaker at the moment, so I attempted to take a screenshot of it but the notifications list closes the moment I press the power button to access the screenshot command.

How do I get around this so I can take a screenshot of the notifications list?

Comment: That's odd. It shouldn't be happening. Anyhow, there are many ways. You can use an app which can take screenshots after `n` seconds. Any [tag:automation] app can do it. Otherwise, record the video for the moment, play it, pause it, and take the snapshot of the relevant scene. [Rec.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spectrl.rec&hl=en) should help in that case. Try  it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long press the volume down and power buttons at same time to capture a screenshot anywhere instead of using power menu selection. Android collapses the status bar as soon as you open power menu, so that will not work.

And use Google Goggles for Chinese translation.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much for the tip about Googles too!

Comment: Welcome friend.Anytime.