# Android CPU usage: What do the red, green and purple bars and the numbers mean?

Tags: task-management, developer-options, cpu

The Internet as a truckload of myths about this. Today, it is time to bust the myths.

When the CPU usage bars that can be enabled in the developer options are being displayed, there is a list of active processes and three numbers above.
Upper right screen corner (also covered by bars):

***14.41 / 20.85 / 40.19***

And then, there are three bars for **each list item**:
*[**Green** bar (usually the longest)] [**red** bar] [**purple**]*

### What do these bars and numbers **actually** mean?

I would appreciate an explaination.

Comment: Your question would be much nicer if you could make a [screenshot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123960/screenshot-of-notifications-on-lollipop) and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

From [Android - Handset built in Developer Tools - “Show Cpu Usage” option meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557155/android-handset-built-in-developer-tools-show-cpu-usage-option-meaning)

[Leszek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265597/leszek)

> Numbers in the first row shows average CPU usage in time intervals 1 minute/5 minutes/15 minutes. Color bars shows how much time CPU spends in userspace(green), kernel(red), i/o(blue).

Also see the accepted answer for a developer explanation

Comment: I see. Why is there no real-time CPU indicator for the last second?

Comment: You asked for meaning - you got it with backing. As to why last second is not shown that is best answered by Google and in any case if you are serious about that you can ask a separate question

Comment: I asked a separate question.